# Slow cheetah not transforming endpoint tags in app.config

Tags: wcf, windows-services, app-config, slowcheetah

i love SlowCheetah for what it is, but having some issues with getting it to transform endpoints in my app.config. I was hoping maybe someone could take a look and see what I am missing or has had this issue in the past.

The app.config default

```
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RFPModel.csdl|res://*/RFPModel.ssdl|res://*/RFPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=developmentServer;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://DevelopmentServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

The Transform for Release is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RFPModel.csdl|res://*/RFPModel.ssdl|res://*/RFPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=releaseServer;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <endpoint address="http://productionServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  </endpoint>

</configuration>
```

I do the normal, create Configurations and make sure before I build that I am in the correct configuration / enviornment, but no matter what I do it stays the same development server even when selecting the Release enviornment / configurations.

Any ideas?

-- UPDATE -- Per request, tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://productionServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RFPModel.csdl|res://*/RFPModel.ssdl|res://*/RFPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=databaseName;initial catalog=dash;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Didn't work

-UPDATE AGAIN ---

Tried your suggestion of connectionString first.. to no avail

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RFPModel.csdl|res://*/RFPModel.ssdl|res://*/RFPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=databaseName;initial catalog=dash;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <client>
      <endpoint address="productionServerName/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </client>


</configuration>
```

Comment: It should be system.serviceModel/client/endpoint, not configuration/endpoint.

Comment: That didn't work. I have done it with Web.config before without adding all of it.. I edited above what I changed

Comment: Try it with connectionStrings first to match the default config file.

Comment: Sorry that did not work.. see above... also weird thing is... both ways, database transform works but endpoint does not... this is an issue in another project I have as well

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, I am back on my dev machine this morning and tried it out and using my first suggestion my config is transforming as expected.

Comment: @asawyer - Can you please post if you don't mind what you had on both machines. I can copy paste and see if maybe there is something my eyes are playing tricks on.

Comment: Sure I'll post it as an answer, won't fit in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working for me, after making the suggestion in my first comment:

*It should be system.serviceModel/client/endpoint, not configuration/endpoint.*

### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows">

    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://DevelopmentServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

### Web.Debug.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://productionServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService" contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

### And the preview transformation compare window:

[image: transformation compare]

Comment: does it matter though that this is a Windows Service using app.config? I've never had any issues using web.config transformations, only app.config in this windows service.

Comment: @gcoleman0828 My current project has 2 windows services, one with a WCF service like yours, everything works fine.

Comment: @gcoleman0828 Silly question, but are you making sure to Save the config file before checking it with the preview tool? It won't save automatically, and won't reflect changes until it's saved.

Comment: Maybe i did do that, because now that I tried that again it works fine. I was trying so many combinations who knows lol. Thank you sir. i will do some more testing and marking you as the answer by EoD

Answer (score 4):

Try SetAttributes transformation:

```
 <system.serviceModel>       
        <client>           
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
address="http://productionServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

You can have comma separated values of attributes, that you need to change.
Though there are only poor examples, hope [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) link will be helpful.

Comment: +1 this worked great for me, although your example has several redundant attributes? I.e. `SetAttributes(address)` and `Match(name)` would suggest only `address` and `name` need to be specified, everything else goes unused?