# ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher due to endpoint transformation failed

Tags: xml, wcf, slowcheetah

I consumed a wcf soap service in a console application, I wanted to use the dev url in my app.config.

I always failed and the error was

> ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

I think the endpoint is not matching the wcf service url due to slow cheetah transformation failed.

```
 <endpoint address="http://wsvc01/xxxDev/xxx.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ixxx" contract="xxxServiceReference.ixxx"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ixxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(address)" />
</client>
```

What I want is to replace address when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure your endpoint dynamically, you can't use the config file approach you're showing here. Rather, you configure all that stuff at run time as the program's starting, using variables to alter the URL of the web service endpoint based on conditions.

Here's a reference to the same topic here in Stackoverflow:
[WCF change endpoint address at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151077/wcf-change-endpoint-address-at-runtime)

Here's another link:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-wcf-hosting-and-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself via the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148511/slow-cheetah-not-transforming-endpoint-tags-in-app-config).
Try SetAttributes transformation:

```
 <system.serviceModel>       
        <client>           
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
address="http://productionServer/WebServices/MasterEngine/MasterEngineService.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
contract="OverlayFarEnd.IMasterEngineService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMasterEngineService"
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```